# image_tag creates src that starts with /images instead of /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I created a class my /lib folder

```
module Blah
  class MyClass
    include ActionView::Helpers

    def meth
      image_tag "default.gif"
    end
  end
```

When I call Blah::MyClass.new.meth I get the following:

```
<img src="/images/default.gif" alt="Default" />
```

Instead of something in the assets/images... folder.

All the other images on the page show up correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does default.gif exist in assets/images? I've seen this occur when the requested asset is missing.

Comment: The default.gif file does exist in assets/images.